# SOQL Query records deleted by cascade

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, cascadedelete

I have a soql query ran in a trigger on AfterDelete of parent that finds all deleted objects that are children of this parent. It looks like this:

```
SELECT Id, FROM child_object_c where ParentID='123' AND IsDeleted=true ALL ROWS
```

However, what I really need is to only get the children records that were deleted as a result of a cascade delete from the parent. This query currently includes *all* deleted children, not just the ones from cascade deletes.

Is there any way to filter the query on whether a record deletion was from a cascade delete?

Comment: Could you just add `Parent.IsDeleted=true`?

Comment: Maybe you could create a formula field Checkbox that contains LastModifiedDate == Parent.LastModifiedDate, then use that in the filter? You may have to build in some sort of way to allow a second or so difference (or maybe more). Also, I'm not 100% sure the LastModifiedDate of the child records actually get updated if they're deleted by a cascade. If it's not you could implement a trigger that runs before delete that updates the then existing child records.

Comment: @BryanAnderson I can't use `Parent.IsDeleted=true` because it is already in the AfterDelete trigger.

@rael_kid, I don't think the LastModified or the SystemModStamp are updated on cascade deletes.... at least not while in the trigger context.

Comment: If you're in the after delete trigger context you might be able to move your logic to the before delete trigger and use the existing (non-deleted) child records.